# How to launch a file in an Electron JS webview?

Tags: electron

How do I get an Electron JS app which is using a webview to save and launch an ICA file?

I am running an Electron JS v18.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.5. It is a simple browser we are hoping to use to view some local web pages - effectively our Intranet.

One page includes links to various Citrix services, each link is an ICA file. If I click on one of these links I just get a 'Save File' dialog from the OS.

I have Chromium installed on the same box and configured to save and launch the ICA files. How do I configure the chromium embedded in Electron JS to behave the same way?